# Why is there no report flag in a profile?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, rude-or-abusive

I was just suggested an edit.

In case you are not able to view the link [here's the screenshot - **Warning: Abusive language**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pt4iU.png)

So I wanted to report [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9846405) user (not just this post). Moreover, this id seems like an attempt-at-revenge to me.

Is there a way we could ban this email id (so that no more ids can be ever created using this email id)?

Comment: Maybe don't inline the extremely offensive edit text in your screenshot

Comment: If they don’t have any posts, you can flag one of your own posts.

Comment: @JF How do I do that? can you please elaborate?

Comment: @BlackBeard find one of your own posts, click flag, select the "needs moderator attention" option, link the applicable user profile.

Comment: @BlackBeard you can comment and flag your comment for mod attention, giving detailed information why you flagged it etc.

Comment: You know, maybe it's time to stop pointing users at the workarounds and just implement profile flagging already.

Comment: @Videonauth can i flag this comment as well?

Comment: @Stijn agreed. SE should take spam and r/a concerns up a notch.

Comment: @Stijn That's what I am asking for. See my question title

Comment: @BlackBeard: how do you mean, flag this comment?

Comment: What I meant was that can I flag any one comment here and ask for moderator's attention towards this post/that profile?

Comment: @BlackBeard you can flag a comment, but since comment flags go into a different queue than post-flags, it's better to flag a post in this case. And yes, just flag a post of your own, link to the profile, explain the situation as best as you can in 500 characters and that's that. Although I think you've reached the mods as well by posting this on meta.

Comment: @Adriaan Still, it feels like a hack to me. Not what I was hoping for.

Comment: We're all hoping for profile flagging, but since that's impossible, this is what we have to do with. Besides, this issue occurred on a specific post which *is* flaggable, so just flag that.

Comment: You can mod-flag the original target post and paste the link to the suggested edit with an explaination. This particular troll has been at it all morning across multiple accounts though, so isn't being picked up by the usual filters.

Comment: They're gone now.

Comment: @JonClements Who are they? (the edits, the user(s), the questions with php tag)

Comment: @AndréKool the Dolphins... They were thankful for the fish though...

Comment: @JonClements As a diamond badge holder (Moderator) can you take this matter to the concerned people? (So that end users do not have to use these type of hacky ways of gaining mod's attention.)

Comment: @NickA now they're gone

Comment: @YvetteColomb what's an **anonymous user**?

Comment: @BlackBeard A user which hasn't registered an account but suggested an edit, it appears as "Improve this post" or something for anonymous users

Comment: @NickA of the comments! I thought you were referring to the user. It's done and thanks for the heads up

Comment: @NickA the situation is being monitored and newly created posts are being deleted. No need to worry!

Comment: @Yvette, [They're not gone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9771417/zoeisafuckingcunt).

Comment: @HansPassant thanks. Please flag them or ping me, either or

Comment: @NickA please flag or ping me here, while I'm around.

Comment: @YvetteColomb As a diamond badge holder (Moderator) can you please take this matter to the concerned people? So that this feature may be implemented (or at least debated on).

Comment: This is the handiwork of one spectacularly uninspired troll.

Comment: @BlackBeard I don't have much pull, it's community support, please see my answer, but I will talk to Tim Post about it, yes.

Comment: @YvetteColomb Do we need to keep [pinging u here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9846741/zoe-is-a-retard)?

Comment: @AndréKool I will move into a chat room. You can ping me there, or mod flag. ping me in here, either way I'll respond immediately, I'm not looking at the mod queue atm

Comment: I want to edit the bold text into `Warning! Profane language` because it isn't really NSFW somehow (For things like violent images or pornography, I would leave it being said "NSFW").

Comment: @JonClements fyi this user has been targeted MULTIPLE times, with at least 5 instances I can personally testify to. Any chance of an IP ban helping here? This person is evil, the target of their harassment is even underage.

Comment: @YvetteColomb - Assuming a profile gets free SEO backlink, I think https://stackoverflow.com/users/10769914/ghayalparinnda 
https://stackoverflow.com/users/10472892/dillmordday
https://stackoverflow.com/users/10640913/ghassanmast
https://stackoverflow.com/users/10535550/viratsala
https://stackoverflow.com/users/7807006/joycedowc
https://stackoverflow.com/users/7078422/debra-foster

 should be removed

Answer (score 27):

Flag the answer that was edited with a custom mod flag. Explain to the mod what happened, link to the proposed edit in the custom description. Then let the mod handle it.

Answer (score 18):

Polygnome's [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/368589/812149) is correct: you use a custom moderator flag on the affected post, with a link to the attempted edit.

That leaves the title question: *why* is there no way to flag an individual user? The answer is that Stack Overflow wants to focus on the content, not on the individual user.
Unfortunately, some trolls abuse this by making accounts that don't have posts. Trolls have created accounts that had no activity beyond just having a hateful name and/or avatar.

If an account has no activity at all, other than just having a trolling name and/or avator... you could try to flag one of your own posts to explain the situation.

*(Since this is now a feature-request):*

**IF** we implement this as a feature, it needs some restrictions. It's easy to imagine a new user, angry at a downvote or comment, flagging another user's profile out of spite.
As a few examples of restrictions:

- it should require a minimum of rep.
- and/or it should only be possible to flag new profiles
- and/or it should only be possible to flag profiles that don't have answers or questions.

With restrictions like that, we can use such a flag against troll accounts, without inviting too much abuse.

Comment: The `good' thing about that kind of rude behaviour is that barely anyone will encounter it, as the usual way of seeing a username/avatar is when they have activity on the site. Doesn't make it any better that it exists though.

Comment: That or post the issue on meta. **But** those seems like hack to me. Why not implement this basic feature of flagging the profile? (And block this email id from further coming back)

Comment: @BlackBeard It's a workaround. You could post a feature request to enable us to flag profiles, though I suspect it will be declined. I expect that people would also use such a flag to simply flag people out of spite :-(  .

Comment: With respect to the e-mail address, I'm pretty sure that once the moderators have destroyed an account, the offending user **will** find it hard to create a new account.

Comment: No they just delete the profile here on SO. AFAIK the don't block the email id from coming back/creating more profiles.

Comment: With "minimum rep" do you mean more than the current 15 required for flagging? And "new" in the sense as with answers, where answers older than 60 days can't be flagged as *Very Low Quality*? The last restriction seems like it can be used for this case indeed.

Comment: @Adriaan Maybe the normal 15 rep required for flagging would be enough; there should at least be _some_ threshold. As for the definition of a new account... I don't think troll accounts last more than a few days, let alone 60. So 60 days should be enough.

Comment: -1. Not enough severity for the dev time when there's already a custom mod flag. Explain it clearly and mods are able to handle it well.

Answer (score 7):

This is an adjunct to flagging. If users are concerned about new accounts popping up with abusive usernames or intentions, I wrote a query here, to search for such accounts.

[Search usernames and about me by any keyword](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/855984/search-usernames-and-about-me-by-any-keyword)

Please flag any and all malicious activity you see. If the account has no posts, custom flag the nearest post or comment with the url and reason in the custom flag reason.

Answer (score -32):

Because Stack Overflow is not a *community* where you interact with users. This is by design, and personally I think it's the most important factor behind its success.

If the user is posting problematic content, by all means, report it. Moderators can see patterns and block or ban a user if necessary.

Comment: There is nothing you can flag at this user since he hasn't produced any flagable content. The username and the rejected edit are problematic. Non of them can be flagged.

Comment: @BDL In which case the workaround is to mod-flag one of your own posts and explain the situation. I've had to do that before with someone who was abusing tag wiki edits, but did not have any Qs or As visible. Not a great solution though.

Comment: Exactly, but the answer says "report problematic content". But it doesn't answer how to do this when there is no reportable content. What you say is absolutely correct, but the answer misses the point.

Comment: @BDL If there is no content to flag, I don't see a problem

Comment: @pipe the problem is that if one has a rude username/avatar/profile text is that **you can't flag that**, since there's no way to flag a user's profile. That's what this question is about, not whether you should flag offensive content. The content is there, there's just no straight-forward way of flagging it.

Comment: @Adriaan Ok, maybe it's just me having a hard time getting upset about something that's not visible. Since there's no content, there's no way to get to it. As soon as there's content, it'll be flagged.

Comment: I just told you, there is content. It's on a profile page. Admitted, it's hard to find, but **the content exists**, they just posted it in a hard-to-find place with no flagging option. You keep on missing the point of this question.

Comment: @Adriaan Yes, you have to actively search for rude words in the list of users to find it. A pretty minor threat.

Comment: @pipe so? If it's hard to find but insulting, it's fine? The user is putting themselves forward by editing, which exposes reviewers to the content. So volunteers who want to take their time to help clean up the site may be shown this... Minor or not, it should be eradicated

Comment: @Patrice I just believe that the ability to flag a _user_ will be more damaging to the website than the current situation.

Comment: @pipe fair. That's somewhat different that 'the content is hard to find, so it's not a problem' though. I don't agree it'll be damaging but I can see how someone could see it that way. I still think this is very different than saying the content isn't a problem because it's hard to find.

Comment: I think the more important point is that sure the profile by itself is very difficult to come across naturally without any _additional_ content; but suggested edits count as additional content because it is content that is being put in front of users. Which begs the question of why there is no option to flag a suggested edit directly. Being able to flag suggested edits would alleviate most of the problem, but users can still be found on the users page. If the name contains a common name plus an expletive or what have you, then it would show up in a search for the common name.

Comment: In this particular case, there was a post by the user in question (since deleted, of course), which could have been flagged.

Comment: Related: *[Is there a community on Stack Exchange/Stack Overflow sites like there is on Quora?](https://www.quora.com/Quora-vs-Stack-Exchange/Is-there-a-community-on-Stack-Exchange-Stack-Overflow-sites-like-there-is-on-Quora)*