# How do we report users?

Tags: support, spam, users

Recently saw this user: https://stackoverflow.com/users/10462488/d-johe post two eidetic answers promoting some bitcoin promotion. Clicked onto users profile but couldn't find a link to report user as bot/spam.

Is this currently a feature or are there plans to implement? Or is this not something worth implementing?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368585/why-is-there-no-report-flag-in-a-profile

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs:  If someone's hurling abuse towards you in comments, use the "harrassment, bigotry or abuse" flag instead of a custom flag.

Comment: I don't find those posts very [eidetic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eidetic) at all…

Comment: @deceze I know Php not English ;) haha I thought it just meant identical, is it identical in this case? :)

Comment: @ThisGuy <drawl>Ma'be you's was tryin'a do a southern accent? Sounds eidetic to me.</drawl>

Comment: @deceze I mean, I am watching texas chainsaw massacre xD

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Flag any post which seeks to promote or advertise services as spam.  These posts are well within the barometer of "spammy" posts, so flagging them as such would be all you need to do.

Comment: but is that far enough to prevent spam/bot users from posting again?

Comment: Yes.  Yes, it is.

Comment: Flagging posts as spam carry a -100 reputation penalty if successful, which carries over into question/answer bans.  So, it may not prevent an *individual* from creating a new account to do it again (and trust me there are plenty of guards to prevent that kind of thing), but it definitely does significantly restrict an individual account from posting spam again.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that ^.^ well in that case, no need for my post here! TY :)

Comment: Actually, it also feeds into the anti-spam systems to help train them, and IIRC, if enough spam comes from an IP, all visitors from it will be rate-limited at the least.