# How can I report User Story spam?

Tags: support, spam

I found this link in a comment on my blog: https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/12869605

How do you report user profiles like this?

[Q374997](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374997/how-do-we-report-users) deals with posts, [Q339215](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339215/how-to-report-users-spamming-in-documentation-requests) with documentation, and [Q368585](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368585/why-is-there-no-report-flag-in-a-profile) with answers.